# How to get Base URL along with href

Tags: php, html, magento

Presently I'm in this location :

```
localhost/magento/dresses/adidas-t-shirt.html
```

I wrote in my file like this

```
<a href="my/hello/">Click Here</a>
```

When I click  on `Click Here`

I am getting like

```
localhost/magento/dresses/my/hello/
```

But actually I'm tryng to get like this

```
localhost/magento/my/hello/
```

How can I get this one?

Comment: may be this should work `<a href="../my/hello/">`

Comment: @Sunil Mishra, what happens for `/localhost/megento/dresses/blue/`?

Comment: You should read about *absolute* vs. *relative* URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also try with below as per magento standard

```
<?php
$_getBase = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
?>
<a href="<?php echo $_getBase; ?>my/hello/">Link</a>
```

Comment: @Naresh, welcome. will you please accept my answer, so if someone has some issue in future so they can utilize our thread.

Answer (score 0):

Your link should be:

```
<a href="/my/hello/">
```

or if you are in a phtml file, you may want to use Magento's native function:

```
<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('...'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to get an URL is:

```
$url = Mage::getUrl('my/hello');
```

This will give you an url like this: `magento_root/my/hello/`. If you want it without the slash at the end use

```
$url = Mage::getUrl('', array('_direct'=>'my/hello'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a base URL set for the application? if not then set a base URL and you can do something like this,

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>my/hello/">Click Here</a>
```

I am not sure about whether you are asking from Megento, if you are then take a look at this. It might be of some help,

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/8812/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for

```
echo $this->getUrl("my/hello");
```